# After Process.wait, $?.exited? is false

Tags: ruby, process

If I run the following:

```
Process.kill "KILL", pid
Process.wait pid
raise "application did not exit" if not $?.exited?
raise "application failed" if not $?.success?
```

I get the error "application did not exit". Why is `Process.wait` not waiting? More precisely, why does `Process.wait` set `$?` to a not-exited status?

Answer (score 0):

The process exited immediately after receiving the kill signal, so Process.wait immediately assigns the appropriate Process::Status object to $? and allows execution to continue.  Process::Status#exited? only returns true when the process exited normally, so what you are seeing is expected behavior -- SIGKILL generally does not cause normal termination.

Answer (score 0):

From the `Process::Status` documentation:

> Posix systems record information on processes using a 16-bit
>        integer. The lower bits record the process status (**stopped,
>        exited, signaled**) and the upper bits possibly contain additional
>        information.

A status of `exited` would mean the process exited by itself (the process called `exit()`). But since you forcibly killed the process it will have a status of `signaled` instead, meaning the process exited because of an uncaught signal (`KILL` in this case).